# SQL statement to combine main table and child table as columns?

Tags: sql-server, xml, pivot

Having a main table and a child table in a Microsoft SQL Server database (2005+), I want to show the user a single table in a grid view which includes rows from the main table and rows from the child table, with the latter one being shown as additional columns.

Please see the following example.

*Main table:*

```
ID | Name
---+--------
20 | Thomas
21 | Martin
22 | John
23 | Mike
```

*Child table:*

```
ID | MainID | Key | Value
---+--------+-----+-----------
1  | 20     | X   | Apple
2  | 20     | Y   | Microsoft
3  | 20     | Z   | Goole
4  | 21     | X   | Dell
5  | 22     | X   | Xing
6  | 22     | Y   | LinkedIn
7  | 22     | Z   | Cisco
8  | 22     | A   | Redhat
9  | 23     | Y   | Logitech
10 | 23     | Z   | Adobe
```

Now what I want to generate is an SQL statement that results in the following result set:

```
ID | Name   | X      | Y         | Z
---+--------+--------+-----------+--------
20 | Thomas | Apple  | Microsoft | Google
21 | Martin | Dell   | <null>    | <null>
22 | John   | Xing   | LinkedIn  | Cisco
23 | Mike   | <null> | Logitech  | Adobe
```

I.e. the child rows are transformed as additional columns.

**My question is:**

Is there a way to achieve this with standard SQL, i.e. without using the [`PIVOT` statement](http://www.tsqltutorials.com/pivot.php) or some [`XML` statements](http://sql-tricks.blogspot.com/2011/04/sql-server-rows-transpose.html)? (because I want to use the query against a VistaDB database, too).

**Update 1**

Then number of detail keys is variable and not limited to 3 or to "X", "Y" and "Z" as names.

Comment: Do you only ever have 3 keys X, Y and Z? That is, fixed columns?

Comment: @gbn Thanks. Unfortunately, this is dynamic. I plan to dynamically generate the SQL statements in code. I'll update the question.

Comment: You'd have to. It can't be done in SQL (unless dynamic SQL or XML) which won't be portable...

Comment: @gbn - do you have a direct SQL statement suggestion/example? lots of `JOIN`s to make one big table?

Comment: Yes, I'd consider lots of self joins per key. However, it will run badly for more than a dozen. TBH, reporting services controls like the Tablix or Matrix will do this for me, especially this looks like a report.

Comment: From SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101423/collapse-table-to-eliminate-null-values/6101698#6101698 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555988/sql-server-pivot-on-key-value-table/4556057#4556057

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways that I see you can do this - one would be with a static query the other with dynamic SQL.

Static query (even though you stated you have an unknown number of columns - this is how you would do this).:

```
select m.id,
  min(case when [key] = 'X' then value else null end) as 'x',
  min(case when [key] = 'y' then value else null end) as 'y',
  min(case when [key] = 'z' then value else null end) as 'z'
from main m
left join child c
  on m.id = c.mainid
group by m.id
```

see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f89b3/3)

Dynamic SQL version, this will create the query:

```
DECLARE @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = ' '
DECLARE @rowcount int
DECLARE @rowNumber int = 0
DECLARE @case as nvarchar(max) = ' '
DECLARE @keyValue as varchar(1)

select distinct [key]
into #temp
from child

-- get the number of unique keys
set @rowcount = (select count(*) from #temp)

while @rowNumber < @rowcount
  begin
    set @keyValue = (select top 1 [key] from #temp)

    set @case 
      = @case + 'min(case when [key] = ''' + @keyValue 
          + ''' then value else null end) as ''' + @keyValue + ''', '

    if @rowNumber < @rowcount
      begin
        set @rowNumber = @rowNumber + 1

        delete from #temp where [key] = @keyValue
      end
  end

set @query 
  = 'select m.id, '+ substring(@case, 1, len(@case) -1) + '
     from main m
     left join child c
       on m.id = c.mainid
     group by m.id'

exec(@query)
```

see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f89b3/21)

The static version is portable but will not work with your dynamic requirement.

Comment: The above doesn't seem to work if you put:
min(case when [key] = 'X' then 1 else 0 end) as 'x' instead of using null

Comment: why would you put that `then 1 else 0` instead of the working correctly `then Value else null`?

Comment: @vig I am not sure why you would want to change that to `min(case when [key] = 'X' then 1 else 0 end)`, can you explain the need to do that?  It won't get you the correct result which is to display the name.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I see this getting done is to use temp tables and looping inside a stored procedure.